# Upload files when it selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an input field. I want it when I select files, it automatically uploads them without pressing any upload button. here is my code. not mentioning the CSS because it is irrelevant. but if you need it I'll provide it.

//html

```
<!-- some codes here-->
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" multiple="true" />
<!-- some codes here-->
```

//javascript

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#fileUpload").on("change", (e)=>{
    var formData = new FormData();
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("file[]", files[i]);
    }
    uploadFormData(formData);
  });

  function uploadFormData(form_data) {
    $.ajax({
      url: ".uploader.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: form_data,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function (data) {
        $("#filenames").html(data);
        $(".alert-container div").removeClass("alert-box alert-err");
        $(".alert-container div").addClass("alert-box alert-ok");
        $("#alertCheck").prop( "checked", true );
        setTimeout(()=>{
          $("#alertCheck").prop( "checked", false );
        }, 5000);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        $(".alert-container div").removeClass("alert-box alert-ok");
        $(".alert-container div").addClass("alert-box alert-err");
        console.log("err");
      },
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? The only problem I can see is that `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files` should be `e.target.files` instead.

Comment: it works. thanks. actually, I just trying to modify drag and drop upload into select and upload. that's it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the way you're accessing the `files` collection from the event. The code you're using right now works for custom jQueryUI event handlers, yet you're using a standard `change` event handler. As such you need to change this line:

```
var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
```

To this:

```
var files = e.target.files;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?
`var files = $("#fileUpload").prop('files');`

Comment: it works too. I wish I can accept both answers.